# Buscar arquivos pela extensão

Tags: c#

Em uma aplicação Windows Forms gostaria de saber como buscar todos os arquivos que existam e contenham a palavra `teste` na extensão de arquivo. Por exemplo, ao abrir uma pasta no Windows e digitar `*.teste*` no campo de busca será retornado todos os arquivos que contenham essa palavra em sua extensão independentemente se for `.teste1`, `.teste2`...

```
 string Diretorio = @"C:\teste\";
 string Arquivo = Diretorio + Codigo.Trim() + "E" + "\" + Data;

 if (File.Exists(Arquivo + ".teste"))
 {
     Retorno = true;
 }
```

No fragmento de código acima, a palavra `teste`foi definida como uma extensão de arquivo. Entretanto se eu tiver o arquivo com a extensão `.teste1` ou `.teste2` o arquivo não será mais encontrado.

Comment: tipo um LIKE na extensão?

Comment: Sim, tipo um like

Comment: mas creio que não seja possível, o exists verifica a existencia ou não do arquivo especificado apenas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode pegar todos arquivos do diretório e ver se as extensões contem o que deseja:

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\teste\");

bool retorno;

string nomeArquivo = "MyFile";

int count = 0;
foreach (FileInfo file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
{
    if (file.Name == nomeArquivo && file.Extension.Contains(".ok"))
        retorno = true;
}
```

Nessa outra opção a baixo é verificado se existe algum arquivo com aquele determinado nome e que contenha na extensão a palavra "ok", caso exista, o `count` retornará maior que 0 e a variável retorno será igual `true`

```
bool retorno = directoryInfo.GetFiles().Where(p => p.Extension.Contains(".ok") && p.Name == nomeArquivo).ToList().Count > 0;
```

Comment: E nesse caso, como seria possível me retornar apenas o ultimo arquivo?

Comment: Ai depende, esse ultimo arquivo vai ser o ultimo criado? se sim, tem `file` tem uma propriedade tem o campo `CreationTime`, você pode usar ele, checa qual está mais perto de hoje

Comment: @Moisolas, não entendi, você está descrevendo problemas diferentes agora. Editei a resposta, nela adicionei dupla verificação, tanto pelo nome, quanto pela extensão. Se usa o `Contais` ele pegará tudo que tiver "teste", seja "testeok" ou "teste1", se quer exatamento aquela extensão, ai seria o caso de usar o `==`

Comment: Mas você precisa apenas confirmar se ele foi impresso, independente da quantidade de vezes ou precisa fazer algo com a quantidade de vezes que foi impresso?

Comment: @Moisolas, fiz um ajuste, confirma se é isso que deseja.

Answer (score 3):

Apenas complementando a resposta do @Barbetta, que está correta. Há um porém, no caso do diretório possuir milhares de arquivos, o tempo de execução poderá ser considerável, ainda mais se estivermos buscando em uma unidade de rede.

Uma maneira mais rápida/limpa de obter essa informação seria usando um *searchPattern* (o mesmo padrão que usamos quando vamos procurar arquivos no Windows).

Exemplo prático para o seu caso em específico:

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Diretorio\", "nomedoarquivo.ok*");
// Para saber a quantidade use a propriedade do array .Length
// int quantidade = files.Length;
```

Para maiores informações consulte a documentação oficial (que possui mais alguns exemplos e explica alguns poréns caso algum dia queira usar um filtro tipo *.xls).

**Link:** https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_