# Como comparar se um texto em excel e igual a parte do nome de uma arquivo em pdf em C#?

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Gostaria de começar um código que lesse uma coluna numa planilha de excel que contem numeros de CNPJ e comparasse com os nomes de arquivos em PDF em uma pasta.

Exemplo: valor numa celula de excel versos nome do arquivo em PDF, se forem iguais true, senão false.

Poderiam me dar uma luz.

Ler a planilha já fiz, mas não sei como percorrer os arquivos em PDF salvos na pasta.

ABAIXO o código que leio os arquivo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    
    string[] arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Projects\MOD01-EnvioDeE-mail\fila\");


    Console.WriteLine("Arquivos:");
    foreach (string arq in arquivos)
    {
        string newArq = arq;
        
        Console.WriteLine(arq);

    }

}
```

ABAIXO o código que leio a planilha.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO; // A BIBLIOTECA DE ENTRADA E SAIDA DE ARQUIVOS
using iTextSharp; //E A BIBLIOTECA ITEXTSHARP E SUAS EXTENÇÕES
using iTextSharp.text; //ESTENSAO 1 (TEXT)
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;//ESTENSAO 2 (PDF)

namespace LerPlanilhaExcel
{
   class Program
   {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        IXLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
        IXLWorksheet ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Sheet");
        wb.SaveAs(@"C:\Projects\LerPlanilhaExcel\LerPlanilhaExcel\excel\MeuExcel.xlsx");

        var workbook = new XLWorkbook(@"C:\Projects\LerPlanilhaExcel\LerPlanilhaExcel\excel\MEI_ATIVO26072021.xlsx");
        StreamWriter logCnpj = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Projects\LerPlanilhaExcel\LerPlanilhaExcel\log\logsCnpj.txt");
        
        int contador = 0;
        int cont = 1;
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= 89; i++) //são 89 praças
        {
            var sheet = workbook.Worksheet(i);
            var linha = 2;
            
            while (true)
            {

                var email = sheet.Cell("O" + linha).Value.ToString();
                var cnpj = sheet.Cell("C" + linha).Value.ToString();
                
                                          
                if (contador == 5) break;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cnpj) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email)))
                {
                    ws.Cell(cont, 1).Value = "CAMPO VAZIO";
                    ws.Cell(cont, 2).Value = "CAMPO VAZIO";
                    wb.SaveAs(@"C:\Projects\LerPlanilhaExcel\LerPlanilhaExcel\excel\MeuExcel.xlsx");
                    contador++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(sheet.ToString() + linha + ": " + cnpj + "---" + email);
                    logCnpj.Write(cnpj + "###" + email + "\r\n");

                    ws.Cell(cont, 1).Value = cnpj;
                    ws.Cell(cont, 2).Value = email;
                    wb.SaveAs(@"C:\Projects\LerPlanilhaExcel\LerPlanilhaExcel\excel\MeuExcel.xlsx");
                }

                if (cnpj == )
                {

                }
                
                                    
                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                linha++;
                cont++;

            }
                        
            contador = 0;

        }
        
        workbook.Dispose();
        logCnpj.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("END");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Buscar arquivos pela extensão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/296284/buscar-arquivos-pela-extens%c3%a3o)

Answer (score 0):

Para percorrer os arquivos de uma pasta você pode utilizar o metodo `GetFiles` de `DirectoryInfo`.

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo("Caminho completo da sua pasta");

//Irá selecionar todos os arquivos que possuem extensão .PDF
FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.pdf");
```

O metodo `GetFiles` retorna um array de `FileInfo`, dessa forma você consegue percorrer o array e fazer a comparação que precisa.

```
foreach (var item in files)
{
    //item.Name é o nome do arquivo 
    if(item.Name == "")
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Certo. Gostaria de comparar um numero tipo assim: valor na planilha do exce: 24585524000150 e est é o nome do arquivo DAS-PGMEI-24585524000150.pdf Acho, que esqueci de explicar isso melhor.

Comment: Beleza, você só precisa manipular essa string e extrair o numero que quer comparar. Esse numero é um CNPJ e sempre vai estar no final do nome? tente dessa forma: string cnpj = item.Name.Substring(item.Name.Length - 18, 14); estou dando um substring nos ultimos 14 caracteres que é o tamanho de um CNPJ. Vai depender de como esse nome do arquivo foi criado.